# Python Rest API, how to sign in to retieve data

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am trying to access a dataset from python available [here](https://ev.caltech.edu/dataset)

[image]

In the API documentation, there is no information on how to sign in using username and password via script. Upon manually entering the API URL into a browser

`https://ev.caltech.edu/api/v1/sessions/caltech/ts`

I have to manually enter the `username: DEMO_TOKEN` and `password: <blank>` and click on sign in to get the JSON response from the server.
[image]

How do I programmatically do that in python?

Below is my snippet which doesn't work

```
import requests
api_url = "https://ev.caltech.edu/api/v1/sessions/caltech/ts"
response = requests.get(api_url)

response.json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, when I do this:

```
import requests
user = "DEMO_TOKEN"
passwd = ""
api_url = "https://ev.caltech.edu/api/v1/sessions/caltech/ts"
response = requests.get(api_url, auth=(user,passwd))
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
```

Please be warned, the json is HUGE.